# Create circular areas around a coordinate

Tags: r, maps, coordinates, circular-dependency, area

I need to create circular areas around a coordinate to identify points inside this circular area. Any ideas how can I do this the easiest way in R?

Comment: You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: Assuming you know the coordinates of the center of the circle and its radius, just compute the distance from each point to the center. If that distance is less than the radius, it is in the circle.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the sf package.  Will need to bring in your data, this differs if you have a spatail data file, or are getting your data from tables.  Then buffer your co-ordinate to get your circular polygon, then intersect that against your points ot get only those that overlap.

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

##if from table data###
CO_ORD <- st_as_sf(x =  "co-ord-data-file.csv", coords=c("Long", "Lat"))

POINTS <- st_as_sf(x = "points-data-file.csv", coords=c("Long", "Lat"))


###if from spatail data file####

CO_ORD <- st_read(dsn="co-ord-spatial-data.gdb", layer="co-ord-layer")

POINTS <- st_read(dsn="poins-spatial-data.gdb", layer="points-layer")



CO_ORD_BUFF <- st_buffer(x = CO_ORD, dist=500)

OVERLAPPING_POINTS <- st_intersection(POINTS, CO_ORD_BUFF)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! but when I try to bring in my data it appears this error
Error: Input must be a vector, not a <sfc_POINT/sfc> object.
Any ideas why is this happening?

Comment: Which line gives the error?  I gave generic options to trya nd cover all cases, a reproducible example of you data woudl help for a more specific answer